# There is a cache miss

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to cache the cypress installation in my build pipeline.

I have this task setup:

```
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'cypress | $(Agent.OS) | package-lock.json'
    path: 'C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\cypress'
```

I've run the build pipeline multiple times but I'm always getting the same error:

> There is a cache miss

[image]

This is the previous build:

[image]

As you can see it's the same fingerprint, so why is the caching not working?

Answer (score 2):

One more thing - In order that cache task works as expected all task must **succeed**.

[image]

Comment: Are you implying that in the first run there will be a `cache miss` and in the second run of the pipeline because the key stores the cache (via the `Post-job: Cache npm dependencies` ) it will have a cache hit?

Comment: Yes, that is true as well - first time it needs to create a cache - it will not find any cache since it doesn't have, but in order to cache anything, all jobs must succeed without warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Check the "cache post-job task" results and see if the keys are different.

In my case I had to use `npm install --no-save` so that the package-lock.json file wasn't regenerated during the pipeline. This ensured the "cache post-job task" was using the same cache key when caching node_modules.

**edit**

Here is an exported example of what we currently use in our pipeline to cache npm modules.

(You must make sure that your **package-lock.json** is checked in to your code repository)

```yaml
steps:
- task: Cache@2
  displayName: 'Npm Install Cache'
  inputs:
    key: '"npm" | "$(Agent.OS)" | my-project/package-lock.json'
    path: 'my-project/node_modules'
    cacheHitVar: NpmInstallCached

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Npm Install'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: my-project/
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'install --no-save'
  condition: ne(variables['NpmInstallCached'], 'true')
```

Comment: As far as I understood, you can only use the cache for `npm ci`, are you sure this is operating?

Comment: @Holdsworth the "cache post-job task results" is on the azure pipeline side where it caches the output of from the cache task. Its not related to the npm cli. 100% `npm install --no-save` still works now.

Comment: Here is an exported example of what we currently use

```yaml
steps:
- task: Cache@2
  displayName: 'Npm Install Cache'
  inputs:
    key: '"npm" | "$(Agent.OS)" | my-project/package-lock.json'
    path: 'my-project/node_modules'
    cacheHitVar: NpmInstallCached

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Npm Install'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: my-project/
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'install --no-save'
  condition: ne(variables['NpmInstallCached'], 'true')
```

Comment: Thanks, I've mentioned since then to make it work, really appreciate your insight @Peter!

Answer (score 0):

1. Set variable `system.debug` to `true` to get more information.
2. You would check the path to see whether it is correct on the agent machine (you are using self-hosted agent, correct?)
3. Usually, on the first run after the task is added, the cache step will report a "cache miss" since the cache identified by this key does not exist. As you always got "cache miss" issue, I suspect the cache is not created or uploaded correctly. You may try to do some modification for `package-lock.json` to recache and re-generated one new key, to see how's the result.

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Also just to add, you can enable pipeline/system diagnostics via the UI when running a pipeline (in the same UI where you choose the branch, this is correct for 7th of June 2022).